# MS Access -Trying to match varying criteria between Lists

Tags: mysql, performance, ms-access

I have been struggling to find a solution to the following.

I have a list of installers, who possess a variety of qualifications.
The installers are in on table, and the qualifications I am tracking are in another.  Currently there are 12 different qualifications, and each installers can have between 0 and 12 to their name.

Separately I have a list of clients, who when having work done for them require a minimum level of qualification per installer. This is set up through a client table, a type of work table, and qualification table.  ( Same table as above so that both sides of the data refer to the same lists.  eg:   Client A, has Roofing Work done.  In order to work on his roofs, each installer must  x out of 12 qualifications listed in the qualifications table.

I am getting stuck on obtaining a list of installers whose qualifications specifically meet  or exceed that required by the client.

The qualifications are specific, in that an installer could have 11 out of the 12 qualifications, however if he does not possess one that is specifically required, he cannot go forward to do the work.

The installer to Qualifications table is 1:many.
I do not want to limit the list of qualifications as these may change or increase over time.

Any guidance forthcoming would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show us your current Table-Definitions. That's make it easier to understand your database. I have problems to difference between whats example and table definiton in your text. Also you are speaking of `MS Access` in your title, but using `mysql` tag too. So what DBMS you are working with?

Comment: Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding.  I have solved the issue by matching the installer with qualifications to the role requirements, and establishing a count of the number of qualifications per installer that matched.

This data was then matched by role and count of qualifications required. Eg: role has 2 qualifications, and that is matched to installers who had 2 matching qualifications.

Thanks